# Get rid of the middle grey line in the workspace

Tags: phpstorm, webstorm

How can I remove that grey line on the code workspace .. 
Image:

- Look at that vertical grey line at the right side ..

[image]

Comment: Came here looking for the same for Spyder, location for version 5.0.0 is Settings -> Completion and linting -> Code style and formatting -> Line length

Answer (score 116, accepted):

**Edit** - As noted in the comments, in more recent versions this is now found at Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Uncheck "Show hard wrap and visual guides"

---

It's called the 'right margin', and it indicates the width of your code, so that if you are trying to comply with a coding standard that requires a maximum width you can easily see where that is.

To remove it completely go into Settings, and under IDE settings find Editor -> Appearance, then uncheck the box marked "Show right margin".

Alternatively, if you want to reposition the line, you can do so under Project Settings -> Code Style -> General, and change the Right Margin value.

Comment: by unchecking _"show right margin"_ , it seems to only visually remove the line, but it is actually still there when you format your code. What I did was to rais the Right margin value to the max of 1000. However, the line still exists. Is there a way to actually remove it completely?

Comment: Not that I know of, although if you look in Editor -> Code Style -> <Your language of choice> you should be able to click the "Wrapping and Braces" tab and see that there are some options for how the right margin value is used. Disclaimer: I use Intellij Ultimate these days, not PHPStorm, so this might not be entirely accurate.

Comment: In GoLand version 2020.2.3, this option is called "Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)", and is found in File/Settings/Editor/General/Appearance.

Comment: This doesn't work in 2021. Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Uncheck "Show hard wrap and visual guides"

Answer (score 33):

**PhpStorm 10**

File > Settings... > Editor > General > Appearance > uncheck "Show right margin (configured in Code Style options)"

[image]
[image]

Comment: In WebStorm 2018.3 IDE "Show right margin" is replaced by "Show hard wrap guide"

Comment: In GoLand version 2020.2.3, this option is called "Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)", and is found in File/Settings/Editor/General/Appearance.

Comment: work for me on phpstorm 2022

Answer (score 20):

In PHPStorm 2017.3 you need to do the following:

Settings > General > Appearance > Uncheck "Show hard wrap guide (configured in code style options)"

Answer (score 8):

In **PHPStorm 8**, Go to `Settings -> Colors and Fonts -> General` then In the right panel menu click `Right margin`  then uncheck `foreground color`

Comment: Thanks, it work also in PHPStorm 2016 under section Editor. I had checked "show right margin" in Appearance but line color was the same as editor background so it seemed as disabled.

Answer (score 8):

In PHPStorm 2020.1 you need to do the following:

Settings > Editor > General > Appearance > Uncheck "Show hard wrap and visual guides (configured in Code Style options)"

Comment: This worked for me, although I had to restart PHPStorm after changing the setting to make the line disappear.

Answer (score 5):

PHPSTORM 9

```
File -> Settings -> Editor -> General -> Appearance:
```

**Un-Check** the box that says "***Show right margin (configured in Code Style options)***"

Answer (score 5):

This is the **Show hard wrap guide (Configured in Code Style options)** in Editors General Appreance settings. However the PhpStorm Version is 2018.*

[PhpStorm Show hard wrap guide (Configured in Code Style options) option](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tN3zR.png)

So you need to go disable or unmark that option to hide that vertical line. From the PhpStorm top bar menu, go to `File > Settings > Editor > General > Appearance` and `Show hard wrap guide (Configured in Code Style options)` checkbox option and unmark to disable it.

Answer (score 5):

As of PHPStorm and WebStorm 2018.3 IDE, The check *"Show right margin"* has been replaced with *"Show hard wrap guide"*. In *Settings → Editor → General → Appearance*

Also *"Right Margin"* value has replaced with *"Hard wrap"* under *Settings → Editor → Code Style*.

Shortcut key to Settings: <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

Settings **(ctrl + alt + s)** > General > Appearance > Uncheck "Show hard wrap and visual guides(configured in code style options)"