# PhpStorm white line at the side

Tags: phpstorm

I am having problems with PhpStorm. After a random keycombination, i have a white line at the side of my editor when i press enter. How do I get rid of it?

Comment: Can you provide a screenshot? Or are there any options or buttons on the white line?

Comment: Hi i just made an account on stackoverdlow so i didn't had the rights to upload a screenshot.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow then :) Are the white lines similair to this question's screenshot? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20351583/get-rid-of-the-middle-grey-line-in-the-workspace

Comment: but there are 4 buttons on the line when you click on it the option to go up and down and return and copy i believe

Comment: I can't seem to recognise it yet, can you provide a link to a screenshot?

Comment: http://imgur.com/i2qKxcz  Here you go

Comment: When do the options on it appear? Can you drag the white line?

Comment: That looks like the VCS diff of currently changed code!

Comment: the options appears on click of the white line and it can't be draged

Comment: but how do i change it ? i did much search on google but can't find it

Answer (score 1):

Most likely you're seeing the [File Status Highlights](https://www.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/help/file-status-highlights.html). It's a visual indication of which lines you have changed since your last VCS commit. To "get rid" of these lines, commit the code to your VCS (git, mercurial, svn, whathaveyou).